# Is there a way to test if an input is an image in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am currently working on a project where you can set images or colours and drag them around. Becouse you can chainge it's appearance I want to give the user 1 command. They can enter a colour or an image. Depending on witch one they enter I must chainge some variables so it doesn't blit colours. Is there a pygame command that can test if the input it's been given is an image or if it's a colour?

Here's the part of my code that uses this

```
def set_appearance(self,appearance): #Enter 1 or 3 colours / images
    if (): #If the input (appearance) is an image
        self.type=1
        if not len(appearance)==1:
            size1=appearance[0].get_rect().size
            size2=appearance[1].get_rect().size
            size3=appearance[2].get_rect().size
            if size1==size2 and size1==size3 and size2==size3:
                self.w=size1[0]
                self.h=size1[1]
                self.allimg=None
                self.inactive=appearance[0]
                self.active=appearance[1]
                self.drag=appearance[2]
        else:
            self.allimg=appearance[0]
            self.w=self.allimg.get_width()
            self.h=self.allimg.get_height()
    if (): #If the input is a colour
        self.type=0
        if len(appearance)==3:
            self.allcol=None
            self.inactive=appearance[0]
            self.active=appearance[1]
            self.drag=appearance[2]
        else:
            self.allcol=appearance[0]
```

Comment: Could you add some of the code. How does the user input it? Could you simply do `if isinstance(Input, pygame.Surface)`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```py
if isinstance(Input, pygame.Surface):
    # [...]
```